# How to config ~/.ssh/config file to remotely access server inside domain

Tags: networking, server, ssh, 18.04, remote-access

I maintain a server on weekly basis that is located inside a client company's network while connected via checkpoint network extender.

I'm able o access with no issues using `ssh root@server.ip@company.dns.domain` after filling my user/pass and the gateway pass, Like this:

```
Gateway authentication and authorization
Please specify the requested information
Gateway username: lucas.csouza
Gateway password: 
root@server.ip@company.dns.domain's password: 
Last login: Wed Jul 11 18:57:55 2018 from
```

---

I'm trying to inform this on **~/.ssh/config** file in an (now) obviously incorrect manner, with no sucess. 
Like below:

```
Host hebs
User root
Hostname server.ip@company.dns.domain
Port 22
```

---

I even tried to use **ProxyCommand** / **ProxyJump** to see if it would pass, but it hasn't worked also. Like below:

## using Proxycommand

```
Host hebs
User root
Hostname server.ip
ProxyCommand ssh company.dns.domain nc %h 22
```

### using ProxyJump

```
Host hebs
User root
Hostname server.ip
ProxyJump lucas.csouza@company.dns.domain:22
```

While using the Proxy approach i was able to see the ASCII art that is display above the Gateway authentication, Like below:

```
::::::::::. ######:: ########: ##::. ##: ##:::: ##:. ######:::::::::::::
:::::::::::......:::........::..::::..::..:::::..:::......::::::::::::::
'########'########'########:'##::::'##'####'##::: ##:::'###:::'##:::::::
... ##..::##.....::##.... ##:###::'###. ##::###:: ##::'## ##:::##:::::::
::: ##::::##:::::::##:::: ##:####'####: ##::####: ##:'##:. ##::##:::::::
::: ##::::######:::########::## ### ##: ##::## ## ##'##:::. ##:##:::::::
::: ##::::##...::::##.. ##:::##. #: ##: ##::##. ####:#########:##:::::::
::: ##::::##:::::::##::. ##::##:.:: ##: ##::##:. ###:##.... ##:##:::::::
::: ##::::########:##:::. ##:##:::: ##'####:##::. ##:##:::: ##:########:
:::..::::........:..:::::..:..:::::..:....:..::::..:..:::::..:........::

Received disconnect from gateway.ip port 22:15: Username doesn't contain '%%' or '@'
Disconnected from gateway.ip port 22
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

---

**Is there a way to correctly fill ~/.ssh/config so that it uses the same "protocol" (sorry, don't know the correct word for this) as with the** `ssh root@server.ip@company.dns.domain` **command??**

Thanks in advance.

---

## additional info

```
lucas@bionic:~$ uname -a
Linux bionic 4.15.0-23-generic #25-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 23 18:02:16 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Using Hp Pavillion 7472 notebook
specs:

- Mem: 15,6 GB
- Proc: Intel Core i7-8550U
- Graph: Intel UHD Graphics 620 (Kabylake GT2)
- GNOME: 3.28.1
- Arch: amd64
- Disk: 1,1 TB (Hybrid 1TB HD / 120GB SSD)

Comment: If you're able to connect via the `ssh` command, then what is it exactly you're trying to do?

Comment: @Terrance since I also maintain a few other servers, I'd like to add these also to my aliases, so that the process is faster

Comment: Since you've established the command line ssh works.  There might be a possibility that the ssh config file won't allow more than one @ while connecting to a host where it automatically will add the @ after the username.  Maybe look into using a bash script instead that you could preset names so it is something like `server_connect alias`.

Comment: But if we consider that: multiple '@' in the connection strings aren't allowed/recognized by the ssh config **in addition to** the fact that if i'm able to connect to the server in question through a ssh command, shouldn't it be possible to configure this same connection using ssh config? Since it shares the same structure as the one used in the ssh command...

Comment: @Terrance I'll also check the possibility to use a bash script for this and i'll post here in case it solves this issue. Thanks for pointing this option out!! I'll just point out that this is not my ideal solution, since i think the ssh config should have a proper way to configure cases like this.

Comment: I just don't know if the part of ssh that controls the aliases sees the line having one @ already in it and fails or not.  I really don't have a way to test this since none of the systems that I ever connect to have more than one @ in them.

Comment: It does look though like you might be doing multiple servers.  See this for configuring multiple jump hosts as the syntax should be the same:  https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/SSH_jump_host

Comment: I don't know if this is what you want but you can perform this with two steps directly in your aliases : `alias myssh='ssh root@company.dns.domain -t '\''root@server.ip'\'''`. 
Hope this help.

Comment: @Terrance For elucidation purposes I've also tried this different ProxyJump approach, testing with and without the user syntax proposed by Łukasz in the answer below, and it didn't work out either way. I appreciate your help, nevertheless!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Host: company.dns.domain
User: root@server.ip
```

because `ssh root@server.ip@company.dns.domain` is recognized by `ssh` as user `root@server.ip` at host `company.dns.domain`.

Comment: Just tested with 4 different servers inside the company's domain and all of them worked out perfecly!

Thanks a lot man! :)